# Default font has no slant=italic but I want to show italic text

Tags: fonts

My preferred font is `-*-fixed-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` and it doesn't have `slant=italic` variation.

I also like `-*-terminus-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` font and under Debian there is special `xfonts-terminus-oblique` package to provide italic font variation.

How to tell Emacs to use `terminus` font for `italic` `:slant`?

I can't use `terminus` as default because it misses some glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

```
(set-frame-font "-*-terminus-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-c-*-*-*")
(setq-default line-spacing nil)
(set-fontset-font nil 'cyrillic "-*-terminus-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-c-*-*-*")
(set-fontset-font nil 'greek "-*-terminus-*-*-*--14-*-*-*-c-*-*-*")
(set-fontset-font nil nil "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
(set-fontset-font nil 'phonetic "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
(set-fontset-font nil 'symbol "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
;; MODIFIER LETTER is not present in terminus, this includes ˌːˈ characters.
(set-fontset-font nil '(#x02C0 . #x02FF) "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
```

I don't understand why

```
(set-fontset-font nil nil "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
```

is not in effect. So I should include

```
(set-fontset-font nil '(#x02C0 . #x02FF) "-misc-fixed-*-*-*--13-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
```